# Function to skip empty variable during concatenation in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Rookie question but can someone help with a simple function to skip empty variables during concatenation in PHP and add a comma.

Example;

```
$addressline1 = "Street";
$addressline2 = "";
$addressline3 = "London";
```

I want to get;

```
$concataddress = "Street, London";
```

And not;

```
$concataddress = "Street, , London";
```

I'm getting the addresses from mysql DB
I can obviously use `if...else` statement and check `if(empty($addressline1))` etc but looking for something efficient and simple.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your code to concat for now ?

Comment: `$concataddress = str_replace(" ,", "", $contactaddress);`

Comment: `implode(', ',array_filter(array($addressline1,$addressline2...)))`

Comment: Why are you thinking `if(){}else{}` and inbuild functions e.g. `empty()` are not efficient and simple?

Comment: @Vatev thanks mate. Please put it as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) without a callback will remove all elements which evaluate to `false`.

```
$concatAddress = implode(', ', array_filter(array(
    $addressline1,
    $addressline2,
    $addressline3,
    ...
)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could place them in an array and use array filter with implode

```
$address = implode(", ", array_filter(array($addressline1, $addressline2, $addressline3));
```

Comment: Boom. Beat me to it :)

Comment: Looks like @Vatev beat me to it too

Answer (score 0):

Try what Vatev suggested:

```
$array = array(
    'Street',
    '',
    'London',
);

$concatAddress = implode(', ', array_filter($array));

echo $concatAddress;
```

Answer (score -1):

You won't get much more efficient with variablenames.

If you store it in an array, you might get more efficient, in the way your code looks good, not in speed really.

for example:

```
function getAdres($ARR_adresParts){
  $adres = array();
  foreach($ARR_adresParts as $onePart){
    if ($onePart !== ""){
      $adres[] = $onePart;
    }
  }
  return implode(", ",$adres);
}
```

And then call it like:

```
$adr = getAdres(array($addressline1,$addressline2,$addressline3));
```

Not nice, but given the situation I doubt it will become more beautiful then something like that. :-)